# How to update SDL Texture with Frame Represented by ffmpeg in AVPicture Format

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-streaming, sdl, sdl-2

I receive a frame of format YUV from ffmpeg, and I convert into RGB format like below:

```
sws_scale(pSwsCtx, (const uint8_t * const *) sFrame->data,
                                                sFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height,
                                                dFrameRGB24->data,
                                                dFrameRGB24->linesize);
```

Now i have a Texture in SDL2 with format of SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB24

**Question:**

How do i Update dFrameRGB24 [ ie AVPicture], into SDL Texture ?

Because

SDL_UpdateTexture Expects raw data, and the number of pixels per line

```
int SDL_UpdateTexture(SDL_Texture*    texture,
                      const SDL_Rect* rect,
                      const void*     pixels,
                      int             pitch)
```

where as

**AVPicture** has the below structure

```
uint8_t * data [AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS]
       pointers to the image data planes
int     linesize [AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS]
    number of bytes per line
```

How can i achieve the same? Kindly help me.

Comment: Is it mandatory for you to use a RGB24 texture in SDL2? You could also use `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_IYUV` for your texture. Then there would be no need for the conversion from YUV to RGB.

Comment: That's right, Updating YUVTexture took me around 50 to 80 millisecond in average, with which i can not display 30 fps.  Hence thought to check with RGB Image.